# Map arguments in functions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm learning elixir and one thing I don't understand the style in which you see maps being arguments in function. The most common place you see this is in controllers like this:

CONTROLLER

```
def create(conn, %{"league" => league_params}) do
  league = %League{}
    |> League.changeset(league_params)
    |> Repo.insert()

  case league do
    {:ok, league} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "League Created Successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
    {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

So, the `create/2` function. The second argument looks like this `%{"league" => league_params}`. Correct me if I'm wrong but that is a map, so why do we reference the value below `League.changeset(league_params)` instead of the key `League.changeset("league")`?

This may seem like a silly question but I can't figure this one out and I can't find docs for this question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Map pattern, the keys are the values to match with a key of the map and the value is the pattern to bind the value of that key to. For example, the pattern `%{"foo" => x}` will successfully match against the map `%{"foo" => 123}` and as a result of the match, the variable `x` will be bound to `123`.

Similarly, in your example, `league_params` will be bound to the value of `params` map's `"league"` key, which is why `league_params` is passed to the changeset. The code is almost equivalent to doing `def create(conn, params)` and then `league_params = params["league"]` in the body of the function. (Almost because if the value doesn't exist, the pattern match will fail but this code will set `league_params` to `nil`.)